# Tweet-Cleaning by removing b' and ASCII - can't find the problem

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, ascii, tweets

I am currently preprocessing tweets, extracted via Twitter API and saved as csv. Within the csv there are some characters like "*b'*" at the beginning of the tweet and code like aren\xe2\x80\x99t, which stands for "*'*". Now I want to remove these chars but don't know how although I have tried it a couple of times. Can anyone help me? I read the file with pandas and Python3. The column is called "*text*"

What I mean is the following:

```
b'RT @username: some text some text C\xe2\x80\xa6' OR

"b'RT @username: some text some text .A\xe2\x80\xa6'
```

Input 1:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data/test.csv', encoding= 'utf8')

df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('b[\s]+', ' ')
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ')
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('[^\u0000-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]',' ')
```

Output 1: Nothing happens.

With the next snippet I tried to apply the UTF-8 encoding. As I am write this need sometimes to be done for further processing.

Input 2:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data/Result_w8_Pfizer_en_test.csv', encoding= 'utf8')
df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
```

Output 2:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-4c6bdb11d736> in <module>
     25 
     26 df = pd.read_csv('Data/test.csv', encoding= 'utf8') # dtype=string
---> 27 df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
     28 
     29 

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6485                          args=args,
   6486                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6487         return op.get_result()
   6488 
   6489     def applymap(self, func):

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    149             return self.apply_raw()
    150 
--> 151         return self.apply_standard()
    152 
    153     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    255 
    256         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 257         self.apply_series_generator()
    258 
    259         # wrap results

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    284             try:
    285                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 286                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    287                     keys.append(v.name)
    288             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-50-4c6bdb11d736> in <lambda>(x)
     25 
     26 df = pd.read_csv('Data/test.csv', encoding= 'utf8') 
---> 27 df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
     28 
     29 

AttributeError: ("module 'pandas' has no attribute 'lib'", 'occurred at index date')
```

Here I did some research but couldn't find out the issue or how to solve it.

Comment: your second error is due to an unrelated error. there seems to be no such thing as `pd.lib.infer_dtype()`

Comment: Any suggestion for my first try? The regex seems to be fine but doesn't remove anything, neither removing the b' nor \xe2\x80\x99t